# Working on Google+ Integration

Tags: php, google-api

```
400. That’s an error.
Error: invalid_request
device_id and device_name are required for private IP: /My Local Host IP /xyz/xyz/googlegoogle_login_oauth/index.php
```

Can anyone help me check for device id and name?

Request Details:

```
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
response_type=code
access_type=offline
redirect_uri=http://local host IP/---/---/google/google_login_oauth/index.php
approval_prompt=force
client_id=---------
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this situation while creating a Google+ web app, but when configuring my Javascript Origin and Redirect URI to a private IP address (like 198.168.1.24).  It seems that Google+ does not like IP addresses, it wants a fully qualified domain names.

Given that my home router provides DHCP and gave me a fully qualified name (such as mycomputer.attlocal.net for example), everything worked much better after changing the origin and URI in the Google Console credentials page.  Make sure you update all your references to IP addresses to names, so you don't end up in an infinite redirect :-)

Hope this helps.